# Sheet Add-on Menu items bring up "install add-on" menu, when the app is already installed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

My add-on worked fine in the Chrome store, but recently Google required apps be migrated to the GSuite Marketplace.

Now, we're running into a problem with the App:

1. It works fine when the user first installs it - the onInstall trigger opens a sidebar for the tool which is functional.
2. Once the user refreshes the page, clicking on any add-on menu items brings up the GSuite Marketplace listing for our add-on instead of creating the sidebar.

The listing shows the add-on is installed, so there's nothing the user can do but close the GSuite listing.

I've read the docs on Auth lifecycle, https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled, but since the app has already been enabled on the document and installed by the user, there shouldn't be any problem opening up a sidebar (which requires auth.LIMITED).

I've tested the add-on locally with my gsuite domain account which published the add-on, and it works fine. The problem described above only happens when the add-on is installed by an ordinary google user account.

I tested opening the sidebar in the onOpen() trigger function, but that isn't supported in auth.NONE mode and I get an error in my logs. For the above problem, I don't see any auth errors in my logs, which makes me think this isn't a problem with authorization modes.

Here's my code for creating a menu and the function for opening the sidebar dialog.

```
function createMenu() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Open tool', 'openSidebar')
  menu.addToUi();
}


function openSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle("Sidebar");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: Does it happen for any ordinary Google user? If it happens for some, consider that their domain admin might restrict the installation of Add-ons.

Comment: It happens with any ordinary Google user. It also lets them install it and works the first time (the sidebar appears upon install). You just can’t ever get the sidebar back again through the add-on’s custom menu.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140187817